# HTML to Word conversion in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ms-word

Rails version: 3.2, Ruby version: 1.9.3

In my Rails app, there is an HTML file which I would like to convert to a Word format without losing its structure/design.

I have used the [htmltoword](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword) gem, but the HTML is not rendered exactly alike in the Word file. It has  design issues. It is not interpreting html elements like `table`, `<ul>` and `<li>` etc. correctly.

I would like to have better suggestions for implementing this feature.

Comment: I think better approach is convert HTML to pdf. If you really not needed word then

Comment: @GaganGami: Yes, it is and I implemented the same. No issues with PDF conversion. But, word is also required..